# sum of columns in a row in sql server 2010

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have the below kind data from a table Mat in sql:

```
Mid    Mat1    Mat2  Mat3   Mat4   Mat5
100     4        5    0     n/a     10
100     1        2    0     3       n/a
100     2        1    n/a   n/a     11
101     2        5    0     n/a     n/a
101     6        20   0     10      n/a
```

now for every mid, we need to sum all the mats exclude the n/a values.

I should get the below data:

```
Mid     Mat1      Mat2      Mat3     Mat4    Mat5
100      7         8         0         3      21
101      8         25        0         10     0
```

can somebody advise how to achieve this in sql query???

Comment: mat1,mat2....becomes which datatype

Comment: these are nvarchar types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
SELECT    
Mid,
  SUM(CAST(case when Mat1='n/a' then null Mat1 else  AS INT)) AS mat1,
  SUM(CAST(case when Mat2='n/a' then null Mat2 else  AS INT)) AS mat2,
  SUM(CAST(case when Mat3='n/a' then null Mat3 else  AS INT)) AS mat3,
  SUM(CAST(case when Mat4='n/a' then null Mat4 else  AS INT)) AS mat4,
  SUM(CAST(case when Mat4='n/a' then null Mat4 else  AS INT)) AS mat4,
  SUM(CAST(case when Mat5='n/a' then null Mat5 else  AS INT)) AS mat5
FROM Mat
GROUP BY Mid
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
select  SUM(cast(Mat1    as int)) as mat1,SUM(cast(Mat2    as int)) as mat2,SUM(cast(Mat3    as int)) as mat3,SUM(cast(Mat4    as int)) as mat4,SUM(cast(Mat4    as int)) as mat4,SUM(cast(Mat5    as int)) as mat5 from Mat group by Mid
```